# How to handle %U through for loop with Linux desktop launcher

Tags: shell, desktop, launcher

I want to make a desktop launcher that opens a list of web pages inside a zip file with Firefox. Here's the code:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Firefox HTZ
Exec=for i in %U; do i=$(printf "%s" "$i" | sed "s|%|%25|g" | sed "s|?|%3F|g" | sed "s|#|%23|g"); firefox "jar:file://$i!/index.html"; done
Type=Application
```

However it just doesn't work. It seems that there's some restriction to the Exec.

I know a workaround is to create a shell script file and invoke it through the launcher. But I'd like to write all of them in the launcher file alone so that it's more easy to setup.

Is there a clear documentation about the restriction of Exec? Is is possible to get the code run using the launcher file alone?

Comment: Did you try invoking your distro's terminal. For example I find `gnome-terminal -e "bash -c '<stuff to execute here>'"` to work fine on my Ubuntu system.

Comment: I'd like to make it POSIX compatibility as long as it's possible. bash -c seems to be an approach, but how can we escape the special characters in %U (possibly containing quotes or other special characters)?

Comment: Quotes can be escaped via `\"`. As for the special characters - what special characters do you mean?

Comment: The `%U` passed to Exec is a list of files, which could possibly contain single quotes, double quotes, spaces, etc. And the %U seems to be pre-expanded before Exec is run. How can we get them properly escaped to be embedded and passed to `bash -c`?